# Is there a Maximum Principle for Biharmonic eigenvalue problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, elliptic-equations

Let $$\Delta^2 u-\lambda u =0$$ where $\lambda>0$ and

$$\Delta^2 u = \frac{\partial ^4 u }{\partial x^4} + 2 \frac{\partial^4 u }{\partial x^2 \partial y^2} + \frac{\partial ^4 u }{\partial y^4}$$

Is there a maximum principle for this equation in a rectangular domain  $[-a,a]\times[-b,b]$ or any other domain?

Fact: it is known that there is a maximum principle for  $$\Delta^2 u =0$$ but not in every domain.

ps: this question arises from another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447956/how-to-solve-the-following-biharmonic-eigenvalue-problem/1456927?noredirect=1#comment2967535_1456927), i.e. that question is solved if the maximum principle exists.

Comment: I think I heard somewhere that those problems lose the maximum principle. This is a thing that I can loosely understand by observing that the solutions to $f''''(x)=0$ in one dimension clearly do not have a maximum principle (unlike $f''(x)=0$ which are affine functions). But you require $\lambda > 0$, so mine is not a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be the eigenfunction for Laplacian with eigenvalue $\mu$. Then

$$\Delta f + \mu f= 0 \Rightarrow \Delta ^2 f + \mu \Delta f =0 \Rightarrow \Delta^2 f - \mu^2 f = 0.$$

Thus if the biharmonic equation satisfy maximum principle with $\lambda >0$, then so is the Laplace equation with arbitrary $\mu \neq 0$.

Comment: nice! 
I think $\Delta f+\mu f=0$ satisfy maximum principle only for $\mu<0$

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky : I cannot recall any maximum principle that is true for all $\mu\neq 0$ too.

Answer (score 4):

I would be surprised if this equation had a maximum principle.

My intuition comes from the corresponding problem in one dimension, which is
$$\tag{1}f^{(4)}(x) =f(x), \qquad x \in (0, 2\pi).$$
This problem fails to have a maximum principle, because it supports the oscillating solution $f(x)=\sin x$.

This solution satisfies Dirichlet's boundary conditions. If you want an example with Neumann's boundary conditions, consider the solution $f(x)=\cos x$.

Also, by translation and rescaling, all problems
$$
u^{(4)}=\lambda u,\qquad x \in (a, b)$$
can be reduced to (1). So, in one dimension one never has a maximum principle.

Comment: you don't need to go that far as higher dimensions...in your example
if you go for $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}2)$ the maximum principle holds
so the dependence on the domain exists even in such simple example...

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky: I disagree. The function $f(x)=\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)$ solves the equation and has a maximum at $x=\frac\pi4\in\left(0, \frac\pi2\right)$.

Comment: Can you please post a reference to this domain dependent maximum principle to $\Delta^2 u =0$?

Comment: Note the both solution satisfies different BC's
I think it was here:
https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CDMQFjACahUKEwiE_bCkv53IAhUHnRoKHVE1B9Y&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathematics-and-its-applications.com%2Fpreview%2Fdec2011%2Fdata%2Fdanet_c.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGSZt763Hkl9Z1rhTV1-fP-6jvCkg&sig2=9TktqLsfiep3WyiAk7eP7g

Comment: or here 
https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CDMQFjACahUKEwiE_bCkv53IAhUHnRoKHVE1B9Y&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathematics-and-its-applications.com%2Fpreview%2Fdec2011%2Fdata%2Fdanet_c.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGSZt763Hkl9Z1rhTV1-fP-6jvCkg&sig2=9TktqLsfiep3WyiAk7eP7g

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky: In those papers, the functions satisfying a maximum principle are not the solutions themselves, but functions of them. For the equation $\Delta^2 u=0$, it is the function $P_9=\lvert\nabla u\rvert^2 -u\Delta u$ that has a maximum principle (note: notations are taken from the linked paper). By the way, if $u(x)=\sin x$ in one dimension, like in our example in this post, then $P_9\equiv 1$.

Comment: I see that I've sent the same link twice, there were another one, can't find it atm....sorry

Answer (score 1):

The first eigenvalue of the clamped square plate is sign-changing, for a  reference see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1470314/92705).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a maximum principle here? There are lots of versions of this rule. I assume you mean that the absolute maximum and minimum of **all** functions defined on the same domain and satisfying the same differential equation will happen on the boundary of the domain. I don't think that such a thing exist for this **eigenvalue problem**. To give some supporting examples for my claim I challenge you to prove such a maximum principle exist for the following simple eigenvalue problems.

**Eigenvalue Problem 1.** Let $V$ be the set of **all** continuous functions $f(x)$ on $[a\,\,\,b]$ satisfying ${{{d^2}f} \over {d{x^2}}}(x) = \lambda f(x)$ on $(a\,\,\,b)$. Can one prove that for **every** function belonging to $V$, the absolute maximum and minimum will occur at $a$ or $b$? I don't think so!

**Eigenvalue Problem 2.** Let $V$ be the set of **all** continuous functions $f(x)$ on $[a\,\,\,b]$ satisfying ${{{d^4}f} \over {d{x^4}}}(x) = \lambda f(x)$ on $(a\,\,\,b)$. Can one prove that for **every** function belonging to $V$, the absolute maximum and minimum will occur at $a$ or $b$? I am afraid **NO**!

Also, I may say that you need such a maximum principle to truly prove the only solution to the biharmonic eigenvalue problem mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447956/how-to-solve-the-following-biharmonic-eigenvalue-problem) is zero. Consequently, I can say that you cannot prove the only solution to the aforementioned biharmonic eigenvalue problem is zero since there is no maximum principle (with the definition I mentioned above) for this problem.