# Undetermined coefficient guessing the particular solution for $y^{"}+k^2y=\sin(kx)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

since the homogeneous solution also has the same form as the nonhomogeneous part I was a bit confused on how to guess the form of the particular solution. any help is greatly appreciated.
My guess is the following
$$Y_P =C \sin(kx) +D \cos(kx)$$ 
but I think the correct guess would be $Y_P=(C+Dx)(A\sin(kx) + B\cos(kx))$ where the $A\sin(kx)+B\cos(kx)$ is our homogeneous solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned the **homogeneous** solution is

$${y_h} = A\cos (kx) + B\sin (kx)\tag{1}$$

and hence your particular solution $y_p$ surely cannot be like $(1)$ as it just make the LHS of the ODE being zero, leaving you with nothing! :)

So we may try particular solutions of the form

$${y_p} = Cx\sin (kx) + Dx\cos (kx)\tag{2}$$

Put it into the ODE to obtain

$$\begin{array}{l}
C\left[ {(2k\cos (kx) - {k^2}x\sin (kx) + {k^2}x\sin (kx)} \right] + \\
D\left[ {( - 2k\sin (kx) - {k^2}x\cos (kx) + {k^2}x\cos (kx)} \right]\\
 = 2Ck\cos (kx) - 2Dk\sin (kx) = \sin (kx)
\end{array}\tag{3}$$

and hence

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
C = 0\\
D =  - \frac{1}{2k}
\end{array} \right.\tag{4}$$

and finally your particular solution is

$${y_P} =  - \frac{1}{2k}x\cos (kx)\tag{5}$$

and your general solution will be

$$y = {y_h} + {y_p} = A\cos (kx) + B\sin (kx) - \frac{1}{2k}x\cos (kx)\tag{6}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE and enjoy the community! :) There is a check mark next to each answer. You can use it to choose the best answer in your own opinion! :)

Comment: @MSB:  Please choose one of the answers above by check marking it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first guess is the general solution of the homogeneous equation. The correct guess is what you believe to be correct, where you can take $C=0$ and $D=1$.

Comment: I think you have made a mistake in choosing proper constants! :) Would you please take a look at [this question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447956/the-biharmonic-eigenvalue-problem-with-dirichlet-boundary-conditions-on-a-rectan) which is related to PDEs. :)

Comment: It was a typo (I wrote $A$ instead of $D$.)

Comment: Again, If you see my answer that choice of constants will not do the job! :)

Comment: Wel, I do not see any difference between my choice of constants and yours in the answer to the present question. What you call $C,D$ I call $A,B$, like in the OP question.

Comment: I mean that there must be some $k$ involved! :) Look at (5) in my answer. Did you look at my question  about PDE Prof? :)

Comment: I did not give the full solution. I just gave a guess for the solution. I left the OP to find the concrete values of the constants.

Comment: Aha! :) I got it!