# orthogonal system and solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem

$\begin{align} u''''=f&& \text{on} \; (0,a) \\ u'=u=0&& \text{on} \; \{0,a\} \end{align} $

for which I have an orthogonal system $\phi_k$

How can I "construct" an orthogonal system for the two dimensional problem

$\begin{align} \Delta^2 u=f&& \text{on} \; (0,a)\times (0,b) \\ u_n=u=0&& \text{on} \; \partial (0,a)\times (0,b)  \end{align} $

where $u_n$ is the derivative in normal direction

Would appreciate any help

Comment: Do you mean $\Delta^2 u = f$?

Comment: Yes. Was a typo @Dylan

Comment: You might find this useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447956/the-biharmonic-eigenvalue-problem-on-a-rectangle-with-dirichlet-boundary-conditi/1492770#1492770